# CI builds fails on TFS2013 when building from other branch than master

Tags: git, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

We have a TFS2013.5 setup to do CI on the development branch from a git repo. When triggering the build manually it builds fine but the automatic build on commit/push fails due to merge conflicts. I've found only one post on another forum about this and I've tried the suggestions there but none of them seems to do the trick. If I compare the output in the drop/src folder after a CI build with my local repo several files are missing.

The message I get from the build is:

```
Exception Message: 20 conflicts prevent checkout (type MergeConflictException)
Exception Data Dictionary:
libgit2.code = -13
libgit2.category = 20
```

Comment: How about you resolve these conflicts first, then trigger one new build?

Comment: @Vicky-MSFT Yes, but that doesn't explain why manually triggering a build works while CI triggered build doesn't.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? My life right now -> https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/wisdom_of_the_ancients.png

Comment: Nope, never got it to work. I'm sorry.